# Cookie not being set in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, koa

I am trying to set a cookie which has my auth token in it. I can see it being returned in the response header `set-cookie: xxxxxx` but for whatever reason, the browser is not storing the cookie.

On my react front end `http://app1.dev:3001` I am making an POST api call as such:

```
return axios.get(
  `${apiUrl}/info`,
  { withCredentials: true }
)
.then(res => res.data)
.catch(console.error)
```

And I have a simple Koa server running on `http://localhost:3000`

```
const Koa = require("koa")
const Router = require("koa-router")
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser")
const cors = require("@koa/cors")
const axios = require("axios")
const env = require("./env")
const KeyGrip = require("keygrip")

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()
const port = env("port")

const keyList = ["xxxxxxx",]
app.keys = new KeyGrip(keyList, "sha256")

router.get("/info", ctx => {
  console.log('req', ctx.req)
  ctx.cookies.set("token", "test_token", { signed: true, httpOnly: true })
  ctx.body = { ok: true }
})

const corsOptions = {
  origin: ctx => ctx.request.header.origin,
  credentials: true
}

app
  .use(cors(corsOptions))
  .use(bodyParser())
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods())

app.listen(port, () => console.info(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

I suspect it is not being set because it is cross domain. when I use `http://localhost:3001` for my front end the cookie gets set fine.

Why are the cookies not being set in browser? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By `browser is not storing the cookie` do you mean that you can't see the cookies in dev tools? Or do you use anything else to figure this out?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I can't see it in dev tools

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `http://localhost:3001` for the frontend, your frontend and backend servers share the same domain (even being on different ports), so you can see the cookie set by a request to your backend server (and so linked to backend server domain).

When you use different domains, you just can't see the cookie as dev tools are attached to a page that belongs to another domain. But the cookie is saved and will be sent back with subsequent requests.

Comment: And this will persist through page refreshes etc? (obviously depending on how to cookie is configured with expiry and session values)

Comment: @Stretch0 yeah, having `withCredentials: true` makes them to be saved and persisted according to regular cookie policies.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyLapin

Comment: I know it's kind of late, but I tried everything and it still doesn't work!

Comment: @chai apparently browsers - specifically chromium, doesn't store cookies with ports!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone having the same problem, this might help.

Frontend:
If using axios then add: `withCredentials: true`.
For fetch() add: `credentials: 'include'.`

Backend:
If you're on `http://localhost:....`  then you could add to your cookie `sameSite:'lax'`, just make sure you're not adding `Secure` to this cookie while you on `http://localhost` because it is only for `https` not `http`, else your cookie won't be added to the browser.
While in production adding `sameSite: 'none'` and `Secure` is ok.

I've added some headers too:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization')
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:3000');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-METHODS',"GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH");
```

Also added:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}))
```

Just make sure you're not using `'*'` when adding your origin as shown above `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:3000')` and `origin: 'http://localhost:3000'`

All of the above helped me with my project, I hope it will help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem .
If you response headers contain this header "cache-control:"no-cache,no-store"
browser wont set cookies, so remove this header from response.